# Can I add some computer/synthesized voices from a computer to my digital piano?

Tags: piano, midi, digital-piano, synthesizer, vst

I just bought a digital piano (gear4music DP-6) and I'm a newbie with electronic pianos. I would like to know if it is possibile to add some computer/synthesized voices to my digital piano using my computer. And if it is possibile, how could I do that. I already downloaded some VSTs but I don't think I can add their sample sounds to my digital piano right?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your piano has MIDI connectors, so you can use it to control VSTs running in a suitable host program on your computer.  There is no way of adding to the sounds made directly from the piano, coming through its speakers or Line Out socket.